# Amsart: Section and subsection titles not formatted properly

Tags: sectioning, formatting, amsart

In overleaf, I initially used the document class extarticle to imitate the format of [Integration with Filters](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.09103), only to realize they used amsart the entire time!

I attempted to convert the article to amsart but the document did not display the author, showed errors with the sections and subsections, and looked nothing like [Integration with Filters](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.09103) (see the code & question below):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{margin=1in,top=3cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=5mm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{TheoStyle}
  \makeatother
\theoremstyle{TheoStyle}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand*{\dt}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\ddt}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subparagraph{%
 \@startsection {subparagraph}{5}{\z@ }{3.25ex \@plus 1ex
 \@minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries }}%
\makeatother
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\makeatother

\title{Finding the Most Generalized, Satisfying Extension of The Mean With Respect To the Hausdorff Measure}

\author{Bharath Krishnan}
\affil[1]{Department of Mathematics, Indiana East University}
\date{December 14, 2022}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.\arabic{enumiv}}

\vspace{-10cm}
\maketitle

\subparagraph{Key Words:} Measure Theory, Means of functions, Hausdorff Measure, Set Theory, Choice Function, Union and Intersection of Measurable sets,  Uniform Cover, Entropy, 

\section{Intro}

\section{Preliminaries}

\subsubsection{Generalized Hausdorff Measure and Mean}

\section{Attempt to Answer Thesis}

\subsection{Intro}

\subsection{Preliminaries}

\subsubsection{Second Half}

\subsection{Proposed Solutions}

\end{document}
```

**Question:** How do I get my paper to have a similar format as [Integration with Filters](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.09103) and keep the code that I added?

Comment: The source to arXiv manuscripts are also availlable. Just click the lin "Other formats" and download and look what they did.

Comment: @egreg has eliminated the "excess" packages in his example, but so you know, `amsart` has `amsthm` built in and preloads `amsmath`.  Further, `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`.  Finally, `hyperref`, with a few documented exceptions, should be loaded last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `amsart` class is not compatible with

- `authblock`
- `titlesec`

Remove them and the related commands.

The class typesets the keywords as a footnote to the first page. You might want to set them differently after `\maketitle`, possibly with `\subsubsection*`. Or as part of the abstract. I show all three methods, take your pick.

The declaration `\newtheoremstyle{TheoStyle}`, as it's in your code is meaningless, because `\newtheoremstyle` takes 9 *mandatory* arguments.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in,top=3cm}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=5mm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newcommand*{\dt}[1]{\accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\ddt}[1]{\accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Finding the Most Generalized, Satisfying Extension of The Mean 
  With Respect To the Hausdorff Measure}

\author{Bharath Krishnan}
\address{Department of Mathematics, Indiana East University}
\date{December 14, 2022}

\begin{abstract}
Some text

\bigskip

\noindent\textit{Keywords.} 
Measure Theory, Means of functions, Hausdorff Measure, 
Set Theory, Choice Function, Union and Intersection of Measurable sets,
Uniform Cover, Entropy

\end{abstract}

\keywords{Measure Theory, Means of functions, Hausdorff Measure, 
  Set Theory, Choice Function, Union and Intersection of Measurable sets,
  Uniform Cover, Entropy}

\maketitle

\subsubsection*{Keywords}
Measure Theory, Means of functions, Hausdorff Measure, 
Set Theory, Choice Function, Union and Intersection of Measurable sets,
Uniform Cover, Entropy


\section{Intro}

Some text for the section. Test $\dt{x}$ and $\ddt{x}$.

\section{Preliminaries}

Some text for the section.

\subsection{Generalized Hausdorff Measure and Mean}

Some text for the subsection.

\section{Attempt to Answer Thesis}

Some text for the section.

\subsection{Intro}

Some text for the subsection.

\subsection{Preliminaries}

Some text for the subsection.

\subsubsection{Second Half}

Some text for the subsection.

\subsection{Proposed Solutions}

Some text for the subsection.

\end{document}
```

[image]